# define_method with predefined keyword arguments

Tags: ruby, introspection

I want to define a method that takes keyword arguments. I would like it to raise when keyword arguments are not provided, and I can code this myself - but ideally I would like to let Ruby do that for me. Also I would like to be able to inspect the freshly defined method using `Method#parameters`. If I use a shorthand double-splat (like `**kwargs`) the actual structure I expect is not visible to `parameters`.

I can of course do this:

```
define_method(:foo) do | foo:, bar: |
  # ...
end
```

which achieves the desired result:

```
method(:foo).parameters
# => [[:keyreq, :foo], [:keyreq, :bar]]
```

but I cannot pass those arguments programmatically, they have to be literally placed in the code. Is there a way I could bypass this?

Comment: Can't you still pass arguments programmatically with `send`? As in `method(:foo).send(params)`

Comment: Are you looking for a way to start with a dynamically defined list of keywords like `[:foo, :bar]` and then define a method with those as keyword arguments? If this is what you are trying to do, the only way to do it would be with `eval`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `eval` to define arguments dynamically (not just keyword arguments), e.g. using [`class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-class_eval):

```
class MyClass
  name = :foo
  args = [:bar, :baz]
  class_eval <<-METHOD, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{name}(#{args.map { |a| "#{a}:" }.join(', ')}) # def foo(bar:, baz:)
      [#{args.join(', ')}]                              #   [bar, baz]
    end                                                 # end
  METHOD
end

MyClass.new.foo(bar: 1, baz: 2)
#=> [1, 2]

MyClass.instance_method(:foo).parameters
#=> [[:keyreq, :bar], [:keyreq, :baz]]
```

Comment: That is always a possibility but I always see `eval()` as a last resort thing, so was wondering about a cleaner way to go.

Comment: The block's arguments within `| ... |` can't be defined programmatically and there's (technically) no other way to pass the method's arguments.